# Duplicate Configuration Profile in Azure Intune?

Tags: azure, sdk, intune

There's a new SDK for Intune and I couldn't find any documentation about it. For test purposes I wanted to create "test profiles", so changes won't apply to devices that are live. So my questions was, is it possible to clone a profile in Intune?

Similar question:
https://microsoftintune.uservoice.com/forums/291681-ideas/suggestions/31932928-copy-clone-duplicate-device-configuration-profile

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I want to share this knownledge here. It's possible through this SDK:
[Microsoft/Intune-PowerShell-SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/Intune-PowerShell-SDK)

To copy a profile by Profile Name, use this command:

```
Get-IntuneDeviceConfigurationPolicy -Filter "displayName eq 'ORGIN-PROFILE-NAME'"  | New-IntuneDeviceConfigurationPolicy -displayName "NEW-PROFILE-NAME"
```